# Finding axis of a cylinder

Tags: geometry

I have to find axis of a cylinder that has the top in the origin and the points $A(-5,6,-4),B(-4,-1,2),C(-1,2,4)$ lie on its lateral area.

Now I know that points A,B,C have the same distance to the axis, but I don't know how I could find this distance ( radius).

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the general equation of a line in 3D through origin i.e. ${x\over a}={y\over b}={z\over c}$

Now calculate distance of the 3 points from this line and equate them . You will get 2 equations with 3 unknowns. So you will get (say) $a\ \&\ b$ in terms of $c$ And hence you will get your desired axis.

Answer (score 0):

So, the axis is through the origin. Place a unit vector there (two variables to fix) and impose that its cross-product with the position vectors for $A,B,C$ be of the same modulus, which will be distance $r$.